# How can you detect the candle previous to the last one?

Tags: pine-script

How can I exit all positions in a strategy on the last historic bar? when=barstate.islast doesn't work because it would execute the order on the next candle (right?).

```
last_historic_bar = is the last bar but not realtime? 
strategy.close_all(last_historic_bar)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the time difference between the current time and the time the current candle will close is less than or equal to 24hrs, this is the last historic candle.

```
one_day_ms = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
last_bar = timenow - time_close <= one_day_ms
strategy.close_all(last_bar)
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28888880)

Comment: There isn't a link in the answer, just the code with the solution.

Comment: Sorry, I did not write correctly. This means that you have entered only one code. It would be much better to write a explanation of the code and how it works.